# How to prevent custom select menus from creating a new page? (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

From the documentation: *"When it has too many options to show on the device's screen, the framework will automatically create a new "page" populated with a standard list view for the options."*. I would like to prevent this from happening. Any idea how? Thanks :)

**Edit:**
The dirty hack is to find and replace `f>h-80` with `0` in your `jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js`

Comment: This question does not have enough information for anyone to either help you or use the information you've posted. Please explain what the actual problem is/was and why you did your "hack."

Answer (score 0):

Use native select menus: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/selects/custom.html

```
<select data-native="true">
    ...
</select>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AYXPs/

Comment: Then why do you care if jQuery Mobile shows the custom menu as a dialog widget?

Comment: Since when the dialog is up the rest of the code doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Comment: Determining what part of your code is actually affected would be a good start. You could comment-out sections until the problem resolves itself, then you know the issue was in the block of code you commented out.

Comment: but setting **data-native = false** or **data-native-menu = false** removes the default css and acts like a basic dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I believe what the OP is looking for is a way to prevent the "page" overlay on larger devices when the option list is long, as it would be for a list of states. The jqm behavior might be fine for a phone or small tablet, but it really causes the display on a desktop device to behave in a manner that makes the programming of the user interface appear amateurish - at least to me anyway.

I have a similar issue but do not yet have a better solution than to use the  data-native-menu="false" attribute.